# running vmstat around a command

Tags: linux, monitoring, vmstat

Im trying to automate a long list of database experiments. I would like to save vmstat output while specific parts of the experiments are running.

Does something exist along the lines of time(1) or script(1) that I could use to say:
" While this command is running, save `vmstat 2`(or similar) output to a file " in my bash scripts

I am aware that vmstat gives my vmstat for the complete system including other processes, but that is OK for my usage.

(Running Ubuntu 9.10 if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vmstat 2 > ~/vmlog.txt &
vmpid=$!
my_funky_command
kill $vmpid
```

Comment: I was hoping I didnt have to do it like that :) I have bad milage with the & operator and $! in my bash scripts (and dd)